# Lagging while switching from fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

i have a main_activity which contains 4 fragments, i can switch between them with Bottom menu.

- first fragment is blank
- 2nd fragment contains a recyclerview
- 3rd fragment contains a recycler view inside a viewpager
- 4th fragment is blank

whene i open the app and switch from the first to 2nd fragment or from the 2nd to 3rd **it's lagging**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

FragmentManager fragmentManager;
AnimatedBottomBar animatedBottomBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    animatedBottomBar=findViewById(R.id.animatedBottomBar);


    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        animatedBottomBar.selectTabById(R.id.home, true);
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, homeFragment)
                .commit();
    }

    animatedBottomBar.setOnTabSelectListener(new AnimatedBottomBar.OnTabSelectListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(int i, @NotNull AnimatedBottomBar.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(int lastIndex, @Nullable AnimatedBottomBar.Tab lastTab, int newIndex, @NotNull AnimatedBottomBar.Tab newTab) {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            switch (newTab.getId()) {
                case R.id.home:
                    fragment = new HomeFragment();
                    break;
                case R.id.events:
                    fragment = new EventsFragment();
                    break;
                case R.id.members:
                    fragment = new MembersFragment();
                    break;
                case R.id.settings:
                    fragment = new SettingsFragment();
                    break;
            }

            if (fragment != null) {
                fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                        .commit();
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error in creating Fragment");
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Lagging how/what? The animation between fragments?

Comment: @emandt no i don't have animation it's lagging while loading the recyclerbiew and the fragments

Comment: If the fragment is already ready and the ListView already attached to its parent, then the lagging depends of RecycleView popolation (too much items? fetching a database or connect to a network resource in the same Thread of UI?). It's difficult to say....